# Why is this Apple example in Swift not working for me?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsession

I am following [this Swift Post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) (published by Apple in September 2016).

The post implements the following **extension** as below:

```
extension Restaurant {
    private let urlComponents: URLComponents // base URL components of the web service
    private let session: URLSession // shared session for interacting with the web service

    static func restaurants(matching query: String, completion: ([Restaurant]) -> Void) {
        var searchURLComponents = urlComponents
        searchURLComponents.path = "/search"
        searchURLComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query)]
        let searchURL = searchURLComponents.url!

        session.dataTask(url: searchURL, completion: { (_, _, data, _)
            var restaurants: [Restaurant] = []

            if let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                for case let result in json["results"] {
                    if let restaurant = Restaurant(json: result) {
                        restaurants.append(restaurant)
                    }
                }
            }

            completion(restaurants)
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

When I try to re-create this in my own project I get the following message:

> Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type '(with: String,
>   completionHandler: () -> ())'

Why there is a discrepancy between the post and what XCode 8.1 tells me? They have been both released at a similar time.

**I am using Swift 3.0**

Comment: This is not Swift3 compatible (Properties in extension, ++).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `in` keyword, should be.

**Edit:**
As @leo noted, also your argument list was wrong, change from:
`(_, _, data, _)` to `(data, response, error)`

So this is what it should be:

```
session.dataTask(url: searchURL, completion: { (data, response, error) in
```

Please note the `in` at the end of the line. This is the syntax for [closures taking arguments](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: @LeoDabus good catch! Did not that that also that might be wrong, just saw the missing "in"